# LINQ2SQL Weirdness With DateTime2

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, linq-to-sql, datetime2

My application logs messages to a database fairly frequently, and so the table uses the DateTime2 type for greater precision.

I'm inserting entries using LINQ2SQL, with the 'Server Data Type' property on the .dbml set to 'DATETIME2 NOT NULL'. Despite this, the precision doesn't always make it through to the DB layer.

I'm inserting entries of the form:

```
LogTime = DateTime.UtcNow,
```

In the DB, most of the LogTime entries are correct up to the millisecond level, but subsequently end with '0026'.

```
2014-01-28 15:37:17.0010026
2014-01-28 15:37:17.0120026
2014-01-28 15:37:17.0310026
2014-01-28 15:37:17.0420026
2014-01-28 15:37:17.0640026
2014-01-28 15:37:17.0830026
2014-01-28 15:37:17.0960026
2014-01-28 15:37:17.1070026
2014-01-28 15:37:17.1180026
2014-01-28 15:37:17.2350026
```

Any idea what's happening here? Is there a trick I'm missing? I should point out that the same section of code that inserts these entries, does occasionally successfully insert entries with the correct level of precision... it's just not consistent.

Comment: Have you looked at the format of Datetime.UtcNow?  It looks like it might be converting Z to 26

Comment: The same section of code is successfully inserting entries with the correct level of granularity, just not consistently. It's an odd one...